# get position of a specific value on an axes of a parallel coordinates plot

Tags: d3.js, axis, parallel-coordinates

Is there a way how i can get the relativ position of a specific value on an axis?

for example:

[image]

getPosition("fiat")
should return something like 0,75
(getPosition is the placeholder for the function i'm searching for)

thanks in advance
Jones

Comment: I'm assuming that you're using D3 to generate this axis. You can simply use the scale object that you used to construct the axis.

Comment: @Lars I'm using the parallel coordinates library to creat the axis and the library is based on d3.js. So i don't use a scale object but maybe the library does. Do you want to see the code i'm using? can you explain how i get access to this scale object and how i have to use it for my issue?

Comment: I don't think you can get the scales from this library. You'd have to modify the source.